# Android Google Endpoints requesting server in production

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-endpoints, publishing

I have just published an app on Google playstore. I am using Google endpoints as my server.

It works fine when I tested app in device using Android Studio.

But when I downloaded my app from PlayStore, Google Endpoint does not seems to respond, and I am not getting data from server.

I again de-installed app and again installed via android studio, it works..

I am sure I am missing something critical here. This is my root Url
https://myappid.appspot.com/_ah/api/

Please help.
Shashank

Comment: Do you have two configuration file for android studio build and release ?

Comment: I am not sure, I did not intentionally do it, does android studio creates different files.. I am still learning :-(

Comment: How should I verify ?

Comment: ok, how are you building your apk for playstore? from your machine or another server using SVN or some source safe ?

Comment: Android studio, "Generate Signed APK" ..

Comment: http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: My Google Endpoint server is responding in production when app is installed via Android Studio, but does not work when app is installed via Google play.

Comment: Any one has faced such problem? Please suggest a solution...

Comment: i really dot know what is the issue, may be your service cant access from out side ;

Comment: Looks like my root should be https://myappid.appspot.com/_ah/spi/ instead of https://myappid.appspot.com/_ah/api/.. any idea ?  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations

Comment: I am thinking, can this be issue related to debug key and production key.. Since app is working in debug mode when I am installing via android studio.  But when I am downloading from playstore, it has now changed to production mode... Please help guys. I am stuck.. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved.

There was a problem with SH1 and MD5 key which was mapped with my debug.keystore..

Solution : I had to open my publish keystorefilename.jks file using command :

> keytool -list -v -keystore keystorefilename.jks

Then I create a new android Oauth2 client ID for android within Google Cloud Console and put it in Endpoint @Api

```
@Api(
        name="myApiName", version = "v1",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "test.com", ownerName = "test.com", packagePath = ""),
        scopes = {Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE, Constants.PLUS_SCOPE},
        clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID, Constants.IOS_CLIENT_ID},
        audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE}
)
```

as ANDROID-CLIENT-ID, and it started working.

Problem solved.

Thanks,
Shashank